# trigger lambda from a button in a static website in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have this static website that has a form with a couple of fields. CloudFront is on front of the bucket routing traffic to the site.

Them form in question naturally has a button that POST to '#'.

Is there a way I could make the hits on the button trigger a lambda function with the content of the form's fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API Gateway is typically used to call the Lambda function from a Web Page.

Here is a basic tutorial matching your architecture: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/