# Can an S3 bucket be used for Registration form input/output?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, registration

I have an AWS S3 bucket and I am trying to create a registration page that will post the input from the form to an API Gateway, and I'm wondering if this is doable on S3. I know that S3 is for static pages, but is there a way to use JS or something else to validate the user input, and then post this to an API Gateway endpoint? I know this would be pretty simple using EC2, but I already have an S3 bucket up, and I can't really tell from looking around online how feasible this is.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 is indeed an overkill here. S3 for static HTML, Lambda Function + API gateway should be sufficient here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60920269/5535604